# Add Query with Month filter to an Access Database with Date/Time Field

Tags: vb.net

I have an Access Database with many fields connected through a datagridview in my vb.net project. Two of these fields contain Date/Time Values. I want to create a query through the query builder that uses input from the user to find records that match the dates the user wants. This "where clause" works :

```
WHERE BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

This creates a toolstrip in which I can input 2 dates so that the query can fill the datagridview with the records.

What I want now is to make a query like the above only this time the user inputs the name of a month he wants (ex. February or 02 ). Is there any way to do that ?

EDIT: Tried using Plutonix's code (Sailing is the Column name) :

```
WHERE SAILING BETWEEN #01/31/yyyy# AND #03/01/yyyy#
```

and I got this error: "Cannot convert entry to valid datetime TO_DATE function might be required"

EDIT 2:  I have created a combobox containing all 12 months and I have a commandbutton. I want to find a way so that if the user selects one of the 12 months from that combobox and clicks the commandbutton, to have the datagridview control (access database) show him only the records that go with that month based on their datetime(Short Date) fields. What code should I put in my commandbutton_click ?

Comment: I'd use a combobox to avoid typos ("febuary") but otherwise the query just needs to bracket the target date/range  `WHERE yourDateColumn BETWEEN #01/31/yyyy# AND #03/01/yyyy#`.  I cant recall if BETWEEN is inclusive or not, but you should get the idea

Comment: I get this error "Cannot convert entry to valid datetime TO_DATE function might be required

Comment: That doesnt sound like a SQL error, so you should show the code you used ([Edit] your question).

Comment: I used the exact code you gave me above.

Comment: you need to use the year in place of "yyyy"!  Also SQL's BETWEEN is inclusive, so after you get the month from the user, you need to calc the start and end of that month (28, 29, 30 or 31 days). If you use SQL params and DateTime types, pass just `dateVar.Date` or the time portion will mess you up.

Comment: Mmm yeah, however I don't want the query to work for one specific timeframe. As i've said above I want the query to get the Month from a textbox like "WHERE BETWEEN ? and ?"

Comment: Then you will have to use Access-SQL and something like `DatePart()` or `Month()` on the column and SELECT those where that expression equals the month number they picked.  You cant use BETWEEN because that works with actual dates.

Comment: Can you please link me a tutorial or a guide on how to use that ?

Comment: `SELECT a, b, c, Month(dateColumnName) As MyMon WHERE MyMon = 2`  fill in your column and table name; this creates a column in the resultset named `MyMon` from the expression  which you can filter on.  If you are using a datatable, you can apply a filter rather than running a query: `myDataView.RowFilter =  "MyMon = 2"`

Comment: I understood that I cannot do what I want through VB's Query Builder ("Add Query). I tried using the Filter with the Bindingsource but it doesn't work either. I have created a combobox containing all 12 months and I have a commandbutton. I want to find a way so that if the user selects one of the 12 months from that combobox and clicks the commandbutton, to have the datagridview control (access database) show him only the records that go with that month based on their datetime(Short Date) fields. What code should I put in my commandbutton_click ?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I created a long query where I added a "Between ? and ?" in my where clause for every Year included in the database (2004-2015), created a huge if clause that gives the beginnings and endings of the month requested for every year and used all those strings to query the database.

```
 If Month.Text = "JANUARY" Then
        A04A = "01/01/04"
        A04B = "31/01/04"
        A05A = "01/01/05"
        A05B = "31/01/05"
        A06A = "01/01/06"
        A06B = "31/01/06"
        A07A = "01/01/07"
        A07B = "31/01/07"
        A08A = "01/01/08"
        A08B = "31/01/08"
        A09A = "01/01/09"
        A09B = "31/01/09"
        A10A = "01/01/10"
        A10B = "31/01/10"
        A11A = "01/01/11"
        A11B = "31/01/11"
        A12A = "01/01/12"
        A12B = "31/01/12"
        A13A = "01/01/13"
        A13B = "31/01/13"
        A14A = "01/01/14"
        A14B = "31/01/14"
        A15A = "01/01/15"
        A15B = "31/01/15"
        A16A = "01/01/16"
        A16B = "31/01/16" 
ElseIf etc etc
```